# missing values for the sqlcmd variables

Tags: sql-server, database, visual-studio-2013, database-project, dacpac

I have build database-project using visual studio. After build successfully, I am trying to upgrade my database using .dacpac file. I am using the linked server in this project. But I have mentioned all the details in that still it giving me following error. I set the variable names in database project.

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately SSMS doesn't allow you to specify the SqlCmd variable values. To deploy a dacpac containing custom SqlCmd variables, you can use either SqlPackage.exe (the path would be something like "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\120\DAC\bin\SqlPackage.exe") or Visual Studio to publish the dacpac.

Comment: "Visual Studio to publish the dacpac" can I publish a dacpac w/ VS?  It seems to generate a SQL script & doesn't use the dacpac for deployment